# Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is unknown

Tags: windows-server-2016, linux-subsystem

I am trying to enable linux subsystem on a Windows Server 2016 on AWS EC2  by following these instructions https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server

Here is the error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux is unknown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

[image]

My windows server is created based on an AWS ami.

How can I find out if my window server supports the linux subsystem? Is there anything I can do to enable the feature?

**Update:**

```
> systeminfo | Select-String "^OS Name","^OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
```

Comment: Have you checked for the right windows version? Run `systeminfo | Select-String "^OS Name","^OS Version"` (from your link)

Comment: I have added the version info to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Server 2016 can't be upgraded to Windows Server 1709. You'll need a different AMI. Unfortunately AWS doesn't offer this currently.

See:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/get-started-with-1709

Henning

Answer (score 2):

Linux Subsystem added in version [1709](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/whats-new-in-windows-server-1709) of Windows Server 2016. To verify the version of Windows you can run `systeminfo | Select-String "^OS Name","^OS Version"`. After updating Windows to the proper version installation should work.

Comment: I have added the version info to the question. I am not entirely clear if it can be upgraded at all or should I create a new ec2 instance based on a different AMI